# Using Selenium to select a specific <li></li> data stream

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm just learning the ins and outs of Selenium with Python so pardon my question if it doesn't come across correctly.

[Inspect Element Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf5il.jpg)

I have successfully pulled in json data from a real time stream of data.  While working with another device that streams the data slightly differently, I can't figure out how to select a specific id/class to grab.

The screen grab shows the layout of the webpage.  This is my code that works fine, but in this particular instance, every second "row" is not the data that I want.  It's separate json data from what I need from the other "rows" How could I target the first, third, or fifth row in this case?

While trying to work with this particular device, it seems that the code will randomly grab one of the rows and sometimes it grabs the right ones and other times it doesn't.  Since these are all called "row" I am not sure how to target a specific one.

Here is the part of my code that grabs the data:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://server.domain/")
    element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "message")
    element.send_keys(box_num)
    element_send = driver.find_element(By.ID, "send")
    element_send.send_keys('\ue007')
    time.sleep(1)
    element_pause = driver.find_element(By.ID, "pause")
    element_pause.send_keys('\ue007')
    # element_class = driver.find_element(By.ID, "stream")
    element_data = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "row")
    data = element_data.text
```

While this code below seems to work, I don't think it's the correct syntax to always work.  A little confused with XPATH syntax so was just toying with it

```
first_li = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='stream']/li[@class='row']")
first_lit = first_li.text
```

Comment: Your XPath is correct, but one way to do it is by using `find_elements()` function and then accessing the elements you want on that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I meant(please note `find_elements()` will actually return a list of `WebElement`s):

```
li_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//ul[@id='stream']/li[@class='row']")
```

then you can access the first, thirds, fifth,... elements by list slicing:

```
li_elements[::2]
```

The doc to `find_elements()` function:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Made perfect sense and works like a charm.  Thanks so much